# Labeling graphs and changing fonts/size in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, label, matlab-figure

**I am trying to label the axis to these figures differently, I am trying to label only one x-axis as "Time(s)", and for the first y-axis as "f(t)" and the second one as "g(t)". All while implementing a certain font and size, my book doesn't explicitly show how to do this, and the internet wasn't very helpful.**

I know I have to implement this but I don't know where in the code I would place this in:

```
% swEPSfigure.m
%
% Set the default font names and sizes for the eps figures
% prepared for Scientific Word
% In SW, a 65-50% reduction of the figures is normally done
% Full LaTeX commands can be used in the labels, legends, etc.
%
%
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontName','Times New Roman');
set(0,'DefaultTextFontName','Times New Roman');
set(0,'DefaultAxesFontSize',18);
set(0,'DefaultTextFontSize',18);
set(0,'defaulttextinterpreter','latex'); % Use LaTeX to add Math symbols
disp(' ');
disp(' Changing Default Font to Times New Roman');
disp(' Changing Default Font Size to 18');
disp(' ');
```

**This is my current code:**

```
x = linspace(0,2);
y1 = sin(2*pi*x);
y2 = exp(-0.5*2*pi*x).*sin(2*pi*x);

figure
subplot(2,1,1);
hPlot1 = plot(x,y1,'rs');

set(gca,'YLim',[-1 2],'YTick',-1:1:2,'XTick',0:.5:2)

subplot(2,1,2);
hPlot2 = plot(x,y2,'k*');

set(gca,'YTick',[-0.2,0,0.2,0.4,0.6],'XTick',0:.5:2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I did answer to identical post.
To change the labels you need to get the handle for the label itself. Fixed code:

```
y1 = sin(2*pi*x);
y2 = exp(-0.5*2*pi*x).*sin(2*pi*x);

figure
subplot(2,1,1);
hPlot1 = plot(x,y1,'rs');

set(gca,'YLim',[-1 2],'YTick',-1:1:2,'XTick',0:.5:2)
set(get(gca,'XLabel'),'String','X axis label 1') %get the handle to XLabel and set its value 
set(get(gca,'YLabel'),'String','Y axis 1') %get the handle to YLabel and set its value 

subplot(2,1,2);
hPlot2 = plot(x,y2,'k*');

set(gca,'YTick',[-0.2,0,0.2,0.4,0.6],'XTick',0:.5:3)
set(get(gca,'XLabel'),'String','X axis label 2') %get the handle to XLabel and set its value 
set(get(gca,'YLabel'),'String','Y axis 2') %get the handle to YLabel and set its value
```